# Another brick in the wall part 2 - teacher or teachers?

Tags: listening, lyrics

I have a question about the song: Another Brick In The Wall, Pt. 2
Pink Floyd

I've been looking for the original lyrics but I can't find them.
In GooglePlay music the lyrics are the following:
https://play.google.com/music/preview/Tznvw345zndudnnmdraikspqesa?lyrics=1&utm_source=google&utm_medium=search&utm_campaign=lyrics&pcampaignid=kp-songlyrics

I have a problem because when I listen to this song, I hear "teacher", not "teachers". Are these lyrics wrong? I can't find the original lyrics. There are a lot of websites where there are different lyrics with "teacher" or "teachers". I can't find the website to rely on.

When I listen to this song I hear "teacher" in all places. The lyrics tell something different.

Help me, please because I want to translate this song into my native language.

Comment: It's heard both ways. Once set of lyrics says "[teachers](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/pinkfloyd/anotherbrickinthewallpartii.html)" and another says it is "[teacher](http://www.songlyrics.com/pink-floyd/another-brick-in-the-wall-pt-2-lyrics/)" on some lines and teachers on others. Without the official [liner notes](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/liner-note), I don't know that it's possible to say one way or the other.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ELL is not a transcription service. Anyway, it's quite possible Waters toggled unpredictably between singular/plural in different performances (or even different verses of one rendition). It would be a daunting task to analyse the wave forms, and you could probably never be sure.

Comment: Re: "I want to translate this song into my native language." Many productions of this song (album, music video, film) make it clear that either an individual teacher or teachers as a group might be addressed, and that the problem isn't about a specific teacher, but about styles of teaching and kinds of educational institutions. As a translator this isn't an original language usage question: instead you should choose whether your think singular or plural think communicates the idea of the song most clearly to your audience in your language of choice.

Comment: There are times when the sung lyrics will differ from the published lyrics, happens more often than you might think.

Answer (score 5):

Lyric sheets online say both, so until I can get home and check my original CD (assuming I can find it) I couldn't say for certain.  Listening to now, the first line is sounds to me like:

> "Teachers leave them kids alone!"

and the following:

> "Hey! Teacher! Leave those kids alone!"

The thing is, it doesn't really matter in this context whether it is singular or plural.  The song is a critique of the British school system (at least at that time), and as such the second "Teacher!" is a *generic noun* that is meant to apply to *any* teacher who participated in that system.

I don't know if your native language has the equivalent of generic nouns, but if you translate the song to mean one, *specific* teacher, it would be incorrect, and *teachers* would be more appropriate.

Comment: Would you rather trust whatever it says on the CD insert, or your ***ears**?* Anyway - what if some of us manage to dig out our ***LP's***, and it turns out that *they* say different?

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I'd certainly want to know what the CD insert says, since it is presumably just a resized reproduction of the original LP insert (if I still had my original LP, I'd use that instead)  But you're right, I'd still *trust* what I hear.

Comment: I'm getting to the time of life where I've start turning on the subtitles in movies, which often include the lyrics to background music. Several times over the last year or two I've been intrigued to notice lyric fragments that I've been mishearing / misremembering for *decades* (not actually including [*Excuse Me While I Kiss This Guy*](https://www.yahoo.com/music/bp/-excuse-me-while-i-kiss-that-guy---music-s-6-most-misheard-lyrics-210920136.html), but you get my drift). By which I mean: "trust" is *always* a "relative" concept, even when it's about "yourself".